# How do i display the data contents of my xml file using pyqt4?

Tags: pyqt

I am trying to build a tiny app to read from an xml file and display on a widget. I don't know which widget to use exactly; QTextBrowser, QTextedit and QWebView. I can't seem to find a good explanation. Please help as much as you can. Before i get, I'm so new to Python, PyQt and my programming ain't good at all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first interprete the xml content into a dom object, and then show whatever you want from that object into your widget. For the first part (detailed info [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom)):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parse('my_xml.xml')
print(dom.toxml()) # .toxml() creates a string from the dom object

def print_some_info(node):
    print('node representation: {0}'.format(node))
    print('.nodeName: ' + node.nodeName)
    print('.nodeValue: {0}'.format(node.nodeValue))
    for child in node.childNodes:
        print_some_info(child)

print_some_info(child)
```

(using e.g. an xml example in file 'my_xml.xml' from  [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#purpose))