# how do i process html form using pyqt?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I am using QTextBrowser to display static html documents. I want to embed forms inside these documents but i can't seem to figure out how am going to process these forms using python or pyqt. The application am building is a desktop app so QWebView ain't much of an option.

Answer (score 0):

Consider whether you *need* to do it in HTML. If you don't, it will be much easier. If possible, use the standard Qt form components.

If for some reason you *do* need to do it in an actual HTML document with HTML forms, you will not be able to do it with a QTextBrowser. Be aware that QTextBrowser has limited functionality; it is not a full browser, but is rather just using a fairly advanced rich-text renderer which supports most of the things in HTML that will be wanted for simple display. Two important things that it doesn't support are JavaScript and forms. QWebView and other things in the QtWebkit package are using a full HTML renderer with all the trimmings (WebKit), so you can use things like forms from them and get more interaction. You will be able to give it a local path (or use a Qt resource), so the fact that it is "a desktop app" doesn't matter, and then you can feed the form data from the page to your app through JavaScript. But you'd be throwing away an awful lot of work that's been done for you already.

If you possibly can, just build your form using standard Qt widgets.

Comment: thank you very much. Honestly, i thought of using QWebView. But the thing is that i don't know anything about it. I'm so new to programming and PyQt. I'm even finding QTextBrowser difficult to use. If you don't mind helping me, i would like to discuss my application with you and show you how far i have gone. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

[Form Extractor Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/webkit-formextractor.html)
Look pythonic version in [pythondir]\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples\webkit\formextractor. This should be installed with PyQt

Answer (score -1):

consider implementing a Python server in your desktop application (read e.g. about the SimpleHTTPServer module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer)).

you can 'serve' your static html or forms containing pages to the browser within your application (requesting pages from 'localhost/...' ) and receive get or post requests.

Comment: thank you so much, i'm grateful. Please if you don't mind, i would appreciate an example. I'd also like to share with you my work for your comments and guide if you don't mind. I have practically no application development experience. Thank you once again.

Comment: I answered your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553944/how-do-i-display-the-data-contents-of-my-xml-file-using-pyqt4) of july 1st, perhaps it helps. On stack overflow, you can 'thank' by upvoting or accepting the answers you like (click the triangle above the 0 at the left of the answer).

Comment: Perhaps you should think over and reconcider if you want a Desktop-app or a web-app. If you go for a desktop app, go for the widgets that come with pyqt (or wxpython, whatever you like more), instead of using html forms. Of course, for a web-app (that you can perfectly access on any desktop with any browser), you use only html forms.